# How is the descriptive text on the new tags page generated?

Tags: support, tags, new-tags-page

The new tags page has descriptions below each tag derived from the tag wiki excerpt. The page seems to chop off the first few words of some excerpts, such as when they start with "[tagname] is" "Questions for", and so on.

How does this filter work exactly, and what words are removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that information is complete, but have a look at this answer of Jeff: [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts/82702#82702).