# Tag summary displaying wrong information?

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts)

When browsing Tags to look for Tag Wikis in need of edits, I came across [sleep](/questions/tagged/sleep), and felt that the Excerpt being displayed needed improvement:
[image]

However, when I go to edit the Tag, the existing excerpt does not seem to match what is being displayed (and the Wiki itself is blank):

[image]

Am I missing something?  Where is the summary "for questions on how to get them to sleep" coming from?  According to the description when I [look at the actual tag](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep), what is being displayed appears to be an oddly truncated version of what should be displayed.

Per the comment discussion in Torben's answer below, it appears that some of the summaries are missing various lengths of the beginning of the summary.

Comment: The 'the "bedtime" tag' is the cause of the clipping here, although I think the check should do a better job of realising the tag mentioned isn't the tag being described. You can *probably* get away with rewording it to "How and when children sleep. For questions about how to get them to sleep, see the bedtime tag", but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean tag *excerpts* and not tag *wikis?* I see the exact same problem (using Win7 + Firefox 15.0) so if you're on a different browser then it's probably a server-side issue.

I looked at the actual tag excerpt and it says:

> How and when children sleep. See the "bedtime" tag for questions on how to get them to sleep.

You can see that the tag excerpt does contain the text `for questions on how to get them to sleep.` This explains your question *where's it coming from* but it does not explain why the first half of the excerpt is missing.

I wonder if there is something in the missing part of the text that triggers a mistake in the server's parsing engine. I've now changed the double quotes to `[bedtime] tag` to see if it makes any difference but there's no change. <strike>Perhaps I need to wait for the server to refresh its internal cache, so I'll check it again tomorrow.</strike> *No, waiting didn't change anything.*

Comment: Yeah, I do mean the excerpt.  I'm using Chrome, but IE 8 shows the same issue.

Comment: I think you've nailed the behavior: it is showing the end of the excerpt, rather than the beginning.  I see the same from [tag:age-appropriate]: only the last few words are being shown when browsing tags.

Comment: The excerpt I just added to [tag:learning] is actually showing the middle of the excerpt, skipping just the first two words.

Comment: This must be a weird system bug. Let's migrate this whole question to MSO!